# has_and_belongs_to_many and unique index on association table generates "Duplicate entry" fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1, associations

I have several `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations and I also used the `uniq` option in associations to avoid MySQL errors in relation with duplicate keys. My associations are like this:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :people, :uniq => true
```

The index I added is a divided primary key I added using:

```
add_index :table_name, [:key_1, :key_2], :unique => true
```

on both sides of the assocation. But when I try to associate an object twice my application throws the `Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '1-9' for key...` error which is generated by MySQL. Is there a smart way to handle this problem?

I have thought about several possible solutions but the arent smart. I thought about changing the INSERT query manually by using the `:insert_sql` option but that would be a lot of work dong this for 20 association tables. Is there a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `uniq` option doesn't try very hard to prevent duplicates from being added - if the association is loaded it will check whether the object is already in there but it won't load the association just to check.

The easiest thing is probably to rescue `ActiveRecord::RecordNonUnique` and deal with it appropriately - no matter how careful your ruby level checks are there's always going to be a chance of a race condition that gets caught by the database

Comment: how can I do this at a central position to keep things DRY? I dont want to resque this error at 20 different places

Comment: opening new thread for this question => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644577/how-to-rescue-exception-central-and-dry