# How to rescue exception central and DRY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, exception, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have an exception that is produced at ~20 seperate places. It can be rescued easy and in the same way at every place but thats not dry and eaven a crapy work! I want to rescue this exception at a central position. How can I arrange this?

Its about the `ActiveRecord::RecordNonUnique` exception by the way,...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this ?

```
def rescue_from_record_non_unique
  yield
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNonUnique
  # your code
end

# ...

rescue_from_record_non_unique do
  # do something
end
```